# configuring apache2 for security

Tags: security, configuration, debian, apache2

in reference to this documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#requiredirectives , in which file should the directives be inserted? e.g. 'Require ip 127.0.0.1'
I'm talking about configuration of apache2 in debian, I want limit access for all except for 127.0.0.1, localhost.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I solved it. the right file to enter the configuration is /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
this is the configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
        Require host localhost
#       Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the IP you wanna grant access in the configuration file of your VirtualHost (default one is on /etc/apache2/sites-avaiable/000-default.conf)

Comment: thanks for fast reply. if I add the code explained in the apache2 documentation, the apache2 restart fails for error